# Why custom lastModified Attribute in model raise error?

Tags: laravel

On Laravel 10 site, in a app/Models/Points.php model I added lastModified attribute :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Config;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Points extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'points';

    public function lastModified(): Attribute
    {
        $lastModifiedValue = ! empty($this->updated_at) ? $this->updated_at : $this->created_at;
        return Attribute::make(get: fn($value) => $lastModifiedValue);
    }

But I got error :

    Undefined property: App\Models\Points::$created_at
```

I tried to use getAttribute method :

```
    $lastModifiedValue = ! empty($this->getAttribute('updated_at')) ? $this->getAttribute('updated_at') : $this->getAttribute('created_at');
    return Attribute::make(get: fn($value) => $lastModifiedValue);
```

But I got another error :

```
Xdebug has detected a possible infinite loop, and aborted your script with a stack depth of '512' frames
```

What is wrong and how that can be fixed ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.43.0"
```